# sequelize, findAll in array

Tags: sequelize.js

Please, help me

How can I find all entries in which the field 'tag' (tag: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.TEXT)) contains something?

something like this (but it doesn't work)

```
tag: {
      [Op.like]: `%${tag}%`,
},
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sequelize [range-operators](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#range-operators)

```
tag: {
      [Op.contains]: tag, // you can also pass [tag1, tag2, ...]
},
```